# How is calculated the density of the 2-almost primes sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, elementary-number-theory

According to the definition of [sequence density](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SequenceDensity.html) at Wolfram's site:

> Let a sequence $\{a_i\}_{(i=1)}^{\infty}$ be strictly increasing and composed of non negative integers. Call $A(n)$ the number of terms not exceeding $n$. Then the density is given by $\lim_{(n\to\infty)}\frac{A(n)}{n}$ if the limit exists.

...for instance the prime numbers should have a density of $\frac{1}{ln(n)}$ evaluated at $n$, because the prime counting function is estimating $\frac{n}{ln(n)}$ primes up to $n$ and thus applied to the definition $$\lim_{(n\to\infty)}\frac{A(n)}{n}=\lim_{(n\to\infty)}\frac{n}{ln(n) \cdot n} = \lim_{(n\to\infty)}\frac{1}{ln(n)}$$

But I am not sure how could I calculate the density of the [2-almost primes](https://oeis.org/A001358) (semiprimes, biprimes, product of two primes) existing up to $n$.

My though is that it could be applied the [formula of the 2-almost prime counting function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPrime.html):

[image]

Where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function, and $p_i$ is the $i^{th}$ prime, so the density would be (*) $$\lim_{(n\to\infty)}\frac{A(n)}{n}=\lim_{(n\to\infty)}\frac{\pi^2(n)}{n}$$

And from that point I am not sure how to proceed, how to manipulate the expression, etc. I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. Is the expression of the density for 2-almost primes (*) correct? If not, how could be fixed?
> 2. If Is it possible to simplify it? Any insights are very welcomed, thank you!

Comment: consider $P(s) = \sum_p p^{-s}$ and $P(s)^2 - P(2s)$. use the prime number theorem that  $\sum_{p < x} 1 \sim x / \ln x$

Comment: @user1952009 thank you for the feedback, then the expression is correct? if you have time and could explain / extend it a little bit in an answer I could accept it.

Comment: I don't want to write an answer, I want help you finding it yourself. What do you get for $P(s)^2 - P(2s)$ ? What can you say of its pole at $s=1$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 your help is appreciated! unfortunately due to my lack of knowledge is difficult to follow, that is why I proposed a brief explanation. Ok, I will try! Well if I do the calculations you explained, for $s=1$ it is $(\sum_p \frac{1}{p})^2-\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}$, then if for the pole I assume that it means that the expression is $=0$ then that means $(\sum_p \frac{1}{p})^2=\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}$ but from that point (if my calculations are what you wanted to express) I can not see how to apply it to reduce the expression I proposed in the question.

Comment: no, $\sum_p 1/p$ diverges... but for $Re(s) > 1$ it converges and : $P(s)^2 = \sum_p \sum_q (pq)^{-s} = 2 \sum_{n = pq, p \ne q} n^{-s} + \sum_{n =p^2} n^{-s}$ hence $$P(s)^2 - P(2s) = \sum_{n = pq, p\ne q} n^{-s} = s \int_1^\infty \pi_2(x) x^{-s-1}dx$$ (the last one by some sort of integration by parts) with $\pi_2$ counting only the integers of the form $pq, p\ne q$